# Why is `poll.poll` faster than `epoll.poll`?

Tags: python, linux, io

I thought `epoll` should be faster than `poll`, but when I do the following experiment, it turns out to be slower.

First I set up 1 server socket with 10 client sockets connected.

```
import socket
server = socket.socket()
server.bind(('127.0.0.1', 7777))
server.listen(1)

clients = [socket.socket() for i in range(10)]
for c in clients:
    c.connect(('127.0.0.1', 7777))
```

Then I registered all clients with both `poll` and `epoll`:

```
import select
ep = select.epoll()
p = select.poll()
for c in clients:
    p.register(c)
    ep.register(c)
```

Finally I use `%timeit` in `IPython` to compare the runtime:

```
%timeit p.poll()
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.26 us per loop
%timeit ep.poll()
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.7 us per loop
```

Maybe the number of sockets are still too small for `epoll` to beat `poll`, but I wonder what's in `epoll` that make it slower when there are not many sockets watched.

Answer (score 0):

The poll system call needs to copy your list of file descriptors to the kernel each time. This happens only once with epoll_ctl, but not every time you call epoll_wait.

Also, epoll_wait is O(1) in respect of the number of descriptors watched1, which means it does not matter whether you wait on one descriptor or on 5,000 or 50,000 descriptors. poll, while being more efficient than select, still has to walk over the list every time (i.e. it is O(N) in respect of number of descriptors).

And lastly, epoll can in addition to the "normal" mode work in "edge triggered" mode, which means the kernel does not need keep track of how much data you've read after you've been signalled readiness. This mode is more difficult to grasp, but somewhat more efficient.

Comment: So `epoll` should be faster, right? How come it ran slower in my experiment?

Comment: No poll is faster from my experience with it

Comment: Then the O(1) implementation of `epoll` must have a large constant `C`.

Comment: It depends what mode you run epoll in mostly and it would make sense if it was always faster but from when I use it poll is faster at least on my computer

Comment: Could you please explain the reason why `poll` is faster even it's using an `O(n)` waiting algorithm.

Comment: Not Really, sorry but I've reached the limit of my knowledge. Quick tip use poll if its shot an epoll if is long.(but no matter what I use poll cause for my pc it runs faster for unknown reasons of uninicorns and wizard potatoes)